# Which naming pattern should i use for basic CRUD?

Tags: java, spring

I'm creating a RestFul API for the first time using spring framework and now im a bit confused about the common labels used to create, read, update and delete. I want to follow a pattern for an easy maintenance in the code.  Is there any rule or naming pattern for the labels that I should follow?

Im thinking about:

```
/service        -> return every services
/service/new    -> create new service
/service/update -> update service
/service/delete -> delete service
```

Comment: use DAO implementation with basic core spring

Comment: Please follow REST best practices when you start to creating some RestFull Services

Comment: I suggest a read of the paper from Roy Fielding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the HTTP verb to control what you want to do with the resouces:

```
GET:    /services        -> returns all elements
GET:    /services/{id}   -> returns element with id
POST:   /services        -> creates a new object, pass the object in the body
PUT:    /services/{id}   -> replace element with id, pass updated values in body
PATCH:  /services/{id}   -> update element with id, pass updated values in body
DELETE: /services/{id}   -> delete element with id
```

I strongly recommend you use query params for paging in GET: /services, return a default number on page 1 if it's not listed.

A full request could look like: http://www.example.com/services?page=5&count=10

Comment: Im not convicted about your answer. If i want to filter my result with more than 1 parameter, should i create something like: GET: /services/{id}/{codeName}/{etc}  ?

Comment: If I understand you correct, yes. GET: /users/102/profile could return full information about a user, or information you dont get from GET /users/102. But I will recommend you to follow best practices and not have more than you need

Comment: If you need to filter using more parameters then use url parameters, so the url path will stay the same. For example `GET: /services?codename=abc&page=1&order=asc`.